# Automate snapshots on platform.sh and must use SSH

Tags: ssh, cron

I am trying to automate the taking of snapshots (restore points) on platform.sh. I first tried to use their yaml file to schedule a cron job, but told that would not work. So now trying to create a cron job that runs from another server to do the task. The difficulty lies in that I must use SSH. After I authenticate I can manually run the job using

```
platform snapshot:create --project=6sglloa4axaxax --environment=dev
```

Not sure where/how to automate that command being run.

Thanks for any insight!

-Matt

Answer (score 0):

Let's call your primary server `serv1` and "another server" `serv2`.

**Method 1.** Create cronjob to SSH to `serv2` and run the command.

1. Generate an SSH keypair using `ssh-keygen`
2. Add the generated public key to `user@serv2:~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
3. In `serv1`, add a cronjob (`crontab -e`) with the command `ssh user@serv2 platform snapshot:create --project=6sglloa4axaxax --environment=dev`

**Method 2.** You can also SSH to `serv1` from `serv1` (not a typo). This is a well-known technique that's used when the affected command requires a complete shell environment. cron's environment is a limited one.

1. Generate an SSH keypair using `ssh-keygen`
2. Add the generated public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
3. In `serv1`, add a cronjob (`crontab -e`) with the command `ssh user@serv1 platform snapshot:create --project=6sglloa4axaxax --environment=dev`

Before you do any of the above, try to make it work as a cronjob. I believe with the right environment variables set, it will properly. In my experience, very few commands can't run as a cronjob.